# How do I highlight current cell from previous cell of a column by jQuery or Java Script on two table in same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I have two tables in a page. First table *id* is personal and second one is employment. This page is render by Ajax method. I want to highlight the cell if  previous cell value is different in two tables. But I can not do this on two table. I can do this on first table only or second table only. Here is the picture below.

[image]

Here is my Code..

```
$("#personal tr").each(function () {
                  $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
                    var currentCell = $(this);
                    var nextCell = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(index).length > 0 ? $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(index) : null;

                    if ( currentCell.text() !== nextCell.text()) {
                        currentCell.css('backgroundColor', '#47d2d6');
                    }
                  });
                });
                $("#employment tr").each(function () {
                  $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
                    var currentCell = $(this);
                    var nextCell = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(index).length > 0 ? $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(index) : null;

                    if ( currentCell.text() !== nextCell.text()) {
                        currentCell.css('backgroundColor', '#47d2d6');
                    }
                  });
                });
```

All  code I wrote in success method in ajax request. I tried before with

```
$("table").each(function () {
  $("tr").each(function () {
              $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
                var currentCell = $(this);
                var nextCell =    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(index).length > 0 ? $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(index) : null;

                if ( currentCell.text() !== nextCell.text()) {
                    currentCell.css('backgroundColor', '#47d2d6');
                }
              });
            });
});
```

but its not working. How to do this ?

Comment: so that means in table 1 if previous cell value is 3 and in table 2 previous cell value is 2 then those 2 cells have to be highlighted?

Comment: No. In table1 row1 the value is 3 and row2 the value is 2. So the row1 cell is highlighted. For row2 the value is 2 and row3 value is 1. So row2 cell is highlighted. But it's not working in table2.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code a bit, by just checking the td's relative to their parent tables

```js
function diffTables(left, right) {

  const $left = $(left).find('td')
  const $right = $(right).find('td')
  const ll = $left.length
  let ii = 0
  
  for (; ii < ll; ++ii) {
    const $leftItem = $left.eq(ii)
    const $rightItem = $right.eq(ii)

    if ($leftItem.text() !== $rightItem.text()) {
      // td's don't have the same value
      $($leftItem).add($rightItem).addClass('different')
    }
  }
}

diffTables('#left', '#right')
```

```css
html {
  font-family: cursive;
}

.different {
  color: red;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="left" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>not</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>same</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="right" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>same</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>same</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will apply this for another purpose. In your code you compare one table to another table. But for me my code working fine  for one table. I compare one row to another row in one table and its highlighted. But not working in second table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. I have solved it by little bit changing of my code. Here is my code..

```
$("tr").each(function () {
                  $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
                    var currentCell = $(this);
                    var nextCell = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(index).length > 0 ? $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td').eq(index) : null;

                    if (nextCell != null && currentCell.text() !== nextCell.text()) {
                        currentCell.css('backgroundColor', '#47d2d6');
                    }
                  });
                });
```

In *if* condition I have added **nextCell != null &&**. Here is my table.

[image]